# How to rerender component inside modalpanel?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2, jboss-4.2.x, richfaces-modal

Is it possible? if yes, how do i do it?

I need to rerender a `<h:outputText>` after an `<a4j:commandLink>` action is executed, both components are inside a modalpanel and that modalpanel is inside a 
I tried:

```html
<a4j:commandLink value="somevalue" id="someid" action="#{MyBean.myAction()}"
    reRender="outputtextid">
    <f:param name="paramid" value="paramvalue"/>
</a4j:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `<h:outputText>` is outside the form that contains the `<a4j:commandLink>` or else it will bind the value of the outputText with the actual value in the form, leading to odd behavior in your page.

```html
<h:form>
    <a4j:commandLink value="somevalue" id="someid" action="#{MyBean.myAction()}"
        reRender="outputtextid">
        <f:param name="paramid" value="paramvalue"/>
    </a4j:commandLink>
</h:form>
<h:outputText value="#{MyBean.outputValue}" id="outputtextid" />
```

If you must have the `<h:outputText>` inside the form, you should consider updating the value using the `oncomplete` tag attribute in the commandLink that executes JavaScript code.

In case you want to show a message to the user, you can use `<h:messages>` or `<rich:messages>` tag component, this will be a better option than using an outputText.

Comment: Thanks Luigi, i was just doing some tests when i ran into this problem, i'll fix it when i get back to work.

Comment: Ok, just to complicate a little bit, the modalpanels are generated by a ui:repeat and i do believe that's why the outputText isn't getting reRendered, any recommendation?

Comment: And it gets worse: the action is executed only one time, i really don't get it

Comment: @PedroRafael Two things: why would you create the `<rich:modalPanel>` inside an `<ui:repeat>`? That looks like a bad design, you only need 1 for the page. If you could explain more about your problem and showing more code, the root problem may be solved (and this one too). Just being a little curious, why do you need to rerender the `<h:outputText>`?

Comment: I'm making a image slider, i realize that `<rich:modalPanel>` inside an `<ui:repeat>` is bad design, but that's what i could do at the moment, each modalpanel generated is one 'slide', i'm trying to change it to only one modalpanel right now, thats why i made a method that change the current image name to be displayed, the `<h:outputText>` purpose is see if the method is working and the image will rerender and change.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. I don't know exactly how to help you, but you could have a look at the [RichFaces 3.3 PhotoAlbum Demo](http://livedemo.exadel.com/photoalbum), there is an image slideshow that uses `<rich:modalPanel>`. The code can be downloaded [here](https://www.jboss.org/richfaces/download/stable.html) in the RichFaces 3.3.3.Final section, RichFaces-example.

Comment: Yes, i saw that, but it uses `<a4j:mediaoutput>` to display the images, which is quite different from `<h:graphicImage>`, i'll take another look at it anyway, thanks again